# Is "somestring@somestring." a valid e-mail address?

Tags: regex, validation, email

When validating e-mail addresses in .NET applications, it has been advised to just use the `MailAddress(String)` constructor, which is supposed to throw an exception if the argument is not in the proper format for an e-mail address.  There are some myths about what does and doesn't qualify as a proper e-mail address, and even Google has been called out for providing a regex that, among other things, improperly disqualifies addresses with tick marks in them.

Now that being said, I've noticed an instance where a string of the format `somestring@somestring.` did not get invalidated by the constructor, despite nothing being to the right of the dot.  I did think everything that didn't use an IP address required a dot and something to the right of it, but [supposedly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address), `admin@mailserver1` is in perfectly valid format.  It's still not quite in the same format though, so I ran a couple of tests [here](http://sqa.fyicenter.com/Online_Test_Tools/Email_Address_Format_Validator.php):

```
o'reilly@somestring.com    - valid
somestring@somestring.     - invalid
```

And [this source](http://www.circleid.com/posts/is_industry_underestimating_the_ending_dot/) makes it sound like `somedomain` and `somedomain.` are both legitimate domain names, and that they are actually equivalent to one another, although it also says that some programs are better than others about handling things like that.

What am I supposed to believe exactly?  There are a lot of .NET developers who use that constructor, instead of a regex, because of its supposed accuracy over most regexes that you would find on the Internet, in addition to it not taking a great deal of time and effort to get right.  I have seen it work in pretty much all other cases I've personally tried.

Is `somestring@somestring.` of the valid format?

Comment: Yes; that is a valid FQDN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Valid email addresses are way more complicated than you'd think. Read [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822) to get an idea of how complicated it is. As well as [RFC 2821](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2821) and [RFC 822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc822.html)

EDIT: [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.4) obsoletes 2822

These are all valid email addresses!

```
"Abc\@def"@example.com
"Fred Bloggs"@example.com
"Joe\\Blow"@example.com
"Abc@def"@example.com
customer/department=shipping@example.com
\$A12345@example.com
!def!xyz%abc@example.com
_somename@example.com
```

I also commonly use email+whatever@gmail.com to subaddress my email. It helps filter my email (and find out where spam came from). See [RFC 5233](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5233)

More on [Phil Haack's blog](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx/)

Comment: You're saying it would be valid?

Comment: `somestring@somestring.` with the trailing `.` is invalid, without it, it's valid. You can also use this to verify http://sphinx.mythic-beasts.com/~pdw/cgi-bin/emailvalidate